# Scheme returning wrong type to apply for list input

Tags: scheme, lisp

I am trying to write a program which will add numbers in a list. However, when I give the input as a list, Scheme does not give me an output.

My code is the following:

```
(define (sumlist lst)
    (cond ( (pair? lst) (+ (car lst) (sumlist(cdr lst))) )))
```

Why does this happen? I am giving input properly, i.e, I am quoting the list.

I am giving input as follows:
`(sumlist '(1 2 3))`

EDIT:
I changed the question slightly. The list was not quoted in `pair? 'lst` and that is why I was getting an error.
Now, I am not getting an error. However, I am not getting any output either.

EDIT2:
I unquoted the list in `pair? lst`. However, now it is giving me the following error: Wrong type in arg2 # 
I have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: I don't think you understand how function application is represented in scheme syntax. That should be `(car lst)` and `(sumlist (cdr lst))`.

Comment: `(pair? 'lst)` looks suspect...

Comment: @leppie That, too. Oddly enough, it was `(pair? lst)` until a few moments ago—the OP edited the question.

Comment: I did what you suggested. Now the error is gone. However, I am not getting any output.

Comment: You're not getting an error because `(pair? 'lst)` is always false, so `sumlist` always returns `#<void>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your function application syntax is wrong. Function application is *always* prefix in Scheme, i.e. `car(lst)` should be `(car lst)`, etc.
2. Also, `(pair? 'lst)` is wrong, since you should not be quoting the argument. That will test if the symbol `lst` is a pair, which is obviously always false.
3. You need a base case for when you *don't* want to recurse—when you receive the empty list—which should return `0`.

Putting all these together, and you should have this:

```
(define (sumlist lst)
  (if (pair? lst)
      (+ (car lst) (sumlist (cdr lst)))
      0))
```

(I also changed `cond` to `if` since `cond` is unnecessary in this case.)

Comment: Why do I need a base case? Doesn't Scheme return the value of the last expression computed? So even if I don't mention a base case, Scheme will return the last expression when the condition `pair? lst` becomes false. Won't it?

Comment: @RohitShinde That doesn't make any sense, first of all, since that would return `#f`, which can't be added to a number. Second of all, it doesn't work like that with `cond`, since `cond` expands into `if` forms, and `if` is a special form. Specifically, `cond` without an `else` clause returns `#<void>` if no conditions match.